# When to use DataFrame.eval() versus pandas.eval() or Python eval()

Tags: python, performance, pandas, eval

I have a few dozen conditions (e.g., `foo > bar`) that I need to evaluate on ~1 MM rows of a `DataFrame`, and the most concise way of writing this is to store these conditions as a list of strings and create a `DataFrame` of boolean results (one row per record x one column per condition).  (User input is *not* being evaluated.)

In the quest for premature optimization, I am trying to determine whether I should write these conditions for evaluation within `DataFrame` (e.g., `df.eval("foo > bar")` or just leave it to Python as in `eval("df.foo > df.bar")`

According to the [documentation on enhancing eval performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval):

> You should not use eval() for simple expressions or for expressions
> involving small DataFrames. In fact, eval() is many orders of
> magnitude slower for smaller expressions/objects than plain ol’
> Python. A good rule of thumb is to only use eval() when you have a
> DataFrame with more than 10,000 rows.

It would be nice to be able to use the `df.eval("foo > bar")` syntax, because my list would be a little more readable, but I can't ever find a case where it's not slower to evaluate.  The documentation shows examples of where `pandas.eval()` is faster than python `eval()` (which matches my experience) but none for `DataFrame.eval()` (which is listed as 'Experimental').

For example, `DataFrame.eval()` is still a clear loser in a not-simple expression on a large-ish `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numexpr
import timeit

someDf = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.uniform(size=int(1e6)), 'b':np.random.uniform(size=int(1e6))})

%timeit -n100 someDf.eval("a**b - a*b > b**a - b/a") # DataFrame.eval() on notional expression
%timeit -n100 eval("someDf['a']**someDf['b'] - someDf['a']*someDf['b'] > someDf['b']**someDf['a'] - someDf['b']/someDf['a']")
%timeit -n100 pd.eval("someDf.a**someDf.b - someDf.a*someDf.b > someDf.b**someDf.a - someDf.b/someDf.a")

100 loops, best of 3: 29.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop
```

So is the benefit of `DataFrame.eval()` merely in simplifying the input, or can we identify circumstances where using this method is actually faster?

Are there any other guidelines for when to use which `eval()`?  (I'm aware that `pandas.eval()` does not support the complete set of operations.)

```
pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.5.1.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US

pandas: 0.18.0
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.2
setuptools: 20.3
Cython: 0.23.4
numpy: 1.10.4
scipy: 0.17.0
statsmodels: None
xarray: None
IPython: 4.1.2
sphinx: 1.3.1
patsy: 0.4.0
dateutil: 2.5.3
pytz: 2016.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.5
matplotlib: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 2.3.2
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.8.4
lxml: 3.6.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.12
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.8
boto: 2.39.0
```

Comment: i would recommend to use `df['colname']` syntax, as it's safer - if you have a _risky_ column names (reserved Python attributes, like `id`, column names with spaces, etc.)

Comment: For more information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases (along with the difference between `pd.eval()` and `df.eval()`), please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So is the benefit of DataFrame.eval() merely in simplifying the input, or can we identify circumstances where using this method is actually faster?

The [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L2130-L2186) for DataFrame.eval() shows that it actually just creates arguments to pass to pd.eval():

```
def eval(self, expr, inplace=None, **kwargs):

    inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
    resolvers = kwargs.pop('resolvers', None)
    kwargs['level'] = kwargs.pop('level', 0) + 1
    if resolvers is None:
        index_resolvers = self._get_index_resolvers()
        resolvers = dict(self.iteritems()), index_resolvers
    if 'target' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['target'] = self
    kwargs['resolvers'] = kwargs.get('resolvers', ()) + tuple(resolvers)
    return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
```

Where _eval() is just an alias for pd.eval() which is imported at the beginning of the module:

```
from pandas.core.computation.eval import eval as _eval
```

So anything that you can do with `df.eval()`, you *could* do with `pd.eval()` + a few extra lines to set things up. As things currently stand, `df.eval()` is never strictly faster than `pd.eval()`. But that doesn't mean there can't be cases where `df.eval()` is just as good as `pd.eval()`, yet more convenient to write.

However, after playing around with the `%prun` magic it appears that the call by `df.eval()` to `df._get_index_resolvers()` adds on a fair bit of time to the `df.eval()` method. Ultimately, `_get_index_resolvers()` ends up calling the `.copy()` method of `numpy.ndarray`, which is what ends up slowing things down. Meanwhile, `pd.eval()` does call `numpy.ndarray.copy()` at some point, but it takes a negligible amount of time (on my machine at least).

Long story short, it appears that `df.eval()` tends to be slower than `pd.eval()` because under the hood it's just `pd.eval()` with extra steps, and these steps are non-trivial.

Comment: This does a good job of describing the usage of `df.eval` vs `pd.eval`.  But what about the differences for `pd.eval` and the ordinary python `eval` function.