# Pandas find values present in at least two groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
                            Distance
Company Driver Document_id          
Salt    Fred   1               592.0
               2               550.0
        John   3               961.0
               4               346.0
Bricks  James  10              244.0
               20              303.0
               30              811.0
        Fred   40              449.0
        James  501             265.0
Sand    Donald 15              378.0
               800             359.0
```

How can I slice that df to see only drivers, who worked for different companies? So the result should be like this:

```
                            Distance
Company Driver Document_id    
Salt    Fred   1               592.0
               2               550.0
Bricks  Fred   40              449.0
```

UPD: My original dataframe is 400k long, so I can't just slice it by index. I'm trying to find general solution to solve problems like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of unique companies a person has worked for, use `groupby` and `unique`:

```
v = (df.index.get_level_values(0)
       .to_series()
       .groupby(df.index.get_level_values(1))
       .nunique())   
# Alternative involving resetting the index, may not be as efficient.
# v = df.reset_index().groupby('Driver').Company.nunique()
v

Driver
Donald    1
Fred      2
James     1
John      1
Name: Company, dtype: int64
```

Now, you can run a query:

```
names = v[v.gt(1)].index.tolist()
df.query("Driver in @names")

                            Distance
Company Driver Document_id          
Salt    Fred   1               592.0
               2               550.0
Bricks  Fred   40              449.0
```

Comment: @AndreyGoloborodko \m/ and `query` is a very powerful API I am trying to promote. If you are interested to learn more, I invite you to go through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval) I wrote recently regarding `query` and `eval`.