# Plot line graph for Pandas Query and Eval function performance

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am comparing the performance of Eval,Query and ndarray and I need to draw a Line plot using the magic function timeit as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(125)
N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Arc':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})


print('===Vectorization with NumPy arrays===')
%timeit df[df.A.values > 5]

print("===Query===")
%timeit df.query('Arc > 10')


print("===Eval===")
%timeit df[df.eval('Arc > 10')]
```

Expected Graph:

source: google

[image]

Comment: There are some examples using `perfplot` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care). Take a look and implement it on your own. Let is know if you have trouble.

Comment: @coldspeed Cool..Thank You!!

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/7AbzcXgH

Comment: I wasn't aware of perfplot. Just check it's documentation and it works like charm...In btwn I am writing a Blog where I am comparing performance of different pandas function and expressions and it seems you have lot of experience on that. Do you mind reviewing my blog before I publish?

Comment: Sure, ping me when it is done and I can take a look. In the meantime, perhaps there is something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval) that you may find useful.

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about. I never down voted any of your answer yet. I am still digesting it..

Comment: Uff sorry, was not meant for you.

Comment: @coldspeed Here is the link for the Blog, Your feedback much appreciated..https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HDSD-4aos6Fbpg6sLCUlTzMJQ5ykLpFW

Comment: It is asking for permission. Can you give me a sharable link that lets me view?

Comment: @coldspeed Here is the gist link: https://gist.github.com/min2bro/f710819b4248d83e9b625c4f4166f1d0

Comment: Have added some comments under the gist. Good luck.

Comment: Oh yes, also do consider upvoting my [query post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval) if you found it helpful. TIA :)

Comment: @coldspeed Sure, I will upvote. Do you mind if I take some points from your eval and query post for my Blog. I would give credit to you on the blog for this..Is it ok?

Comment: By all means, please do so.

Comment: Thanks..You are a Gem...

Comment: Can I ask for your email id? so that I can share the blog link with you after I publish..

Comment: <email redacted> let me know if you didn't get that.