# Define a new column in pandas dataframe dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

Say I define the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
print(df.head())
```

and I want to generate a new column by using some condition on the existing column(s)

```
df['XXX'] = df.AAA < 6
print(df.head())
```

where the output generated would be:

```
     AAA BBB CCC  XXX
0    4   10  100  True
1    5   20   50  True
2    6   30  -30  False
3    7   40  -50  False
```

I'd like to be able to generate these conditions dynamically, for example by passing something like

```
"AAA < 6"
```

or

```
"AAA < 4 & BBB == 10"
```

and have these conditions evaluated accordingly.

Does pandas provide some mechanism to allow something like this? I know eval() could be an alternative, but also note that the above strings would also need to be given the df as a context, ie: "AAA < 6" => "df.AAA < 6"

Alternatively, could someone recommend me a package which would allow me to define these conditions and then generate a lambda or similar which could be used to evaluate?

Thank you

Comment: `df.eval('XXX = AAA < 6')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
df['a'] = df.eval("AAA < 5 & BBB == 10")
df['b'] = df.eval("AAA < 6")
df['c'] = df.eval("AAA < 4 & BBB == 10")
print (df)

   AAA  BBB  CCC      a      b      c
0    4   10  100   True   True  False
1    5   20   50  False   True  False
2    6   30  -30  False  False  False
3    7   40  -50  False  False  False
```

More information about using this function with alternatives is [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/2901002)

Comment: Can't believe I missed this method. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - You are welcome! More information about this function is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/2901002)

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas' [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html), which can evaluate a string describing operations:

```
cond = "AAA < 6"
df.eval(cond)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: AAA, dtype: bool
```

---

```
cond = "AAA < 6"
df.assign(XXX = df.eval(cond))

 AAA  BBB  CCC    XXX
0    4   10  100   True
1    5   20   50   True
2    6   30  -30  False
3    7   40  -50  False

cond = "AAA < 4 & BBB == 10"
df.assign(XXX = df.eval(cond))

AAA  BBB  CCC    XXX
0    4   10  100  False
1    5   20   50  False
2    6   30  -30  False
3    7   40  -50  False
```