# Filter pandas GroupBy output in a single step (method chaining)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I would like to filter the results of a pandas groupBy directly, without having to store the groupBy result in a variable first. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([("a", 1)]*3+[("b", 1)]*2+[("c", 1)], columns=["title", "counts"])

res = df.groupby("title").agg({"counts":"sum"}) # I want to skip creating res

my_res = res.loc[res.counts >2]
```

In the above example, I would like to create `my_res` with an one-liner. In Spark/Scala this can be achieved simply by chaining a filter operation, but in pandas filter has a different purpose.

Comment: `df.groupby("title").agg({"counts":"sum"}).query('counts > 2')`

Comment: I would also recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53779986/4909087) post of mine.

Comment: Thank you, it does the work. If you want to post an answer, I will accept it; I will check the recommended post also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `query` to chain this step:

```
df.groupby("title").agg({"counts":"sum"}).query('counts > 2')

       counts
title        
a           3
```