# Extension dtypes in pandas appear to have a bug with query

Tags: pandas

**(2/19/2019):
I opened up a report in the numexpr tracker:
https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/331**

**The pandas report is:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25369**

Unless I'm doing something I'm not supposed to, 
the new dtype extensions for nullable int appear to have a bug with the QUERY method on dataframe (the problem seems to be in the numexpr package):

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[4,5,6], columns=["col_test"])
df_test = df_test.astype(dtype={"col_test": pd.Int32Dtype()})
df_test.query("col_test != 6")
```

Last lines of the long error message are:

> File "...\site_packages\numexpr\necompiler.py", line 822, in evaluate
>       zip(names, arguments)]   File "...\site_packages\numexpr\necompiler.py", line 821, in 
>       signature = [(name, getType(arg)) for (name, arg) in   File "...\site_packages\numexpr\necompiler.py", line 703, in getType
>       raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name) ValueError: unknown type object

The non-extension dtypes work fine:

```
df_test = df_test.astype(dtype={"col_test": np.int32})
df_test.query("col_test != 6")
```

(p.s. as an entirely separate issue, passing the dtype 
to the pd.DataFrame constructor directly doesn't work--seems buggy).

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Extension dtypes have been introduced for the first time in 0.24, and there are a lot of kinks to iron out.

That said, this seems to be some kind of compatibility issue between numexpr and pandas. This definitely looks buggy, and until it is fixed, we will have to fall back to the `'python'` engine.

```
df_test.query('col_test != 6', engine='python')

   col_test
0         4
1         5
```

(More information on `query`/`eval`: [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53779986/4909087))

Notwithstanding the fact that you could just do

```
df_test.loc[df_test['col_test'] != 6]

   col_test
0         4
1         5
```

Which is likely to be a lot faster (using `engine='python'` offers no performance benefits over `loc`).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful (and such a quick response!)  Unfortunately query is a lot easier to use in my real (non-reported) case, partly because I'm mixing one multi-index column name with regular columns in the query.  As far as I know, there's no easy way to use loc with that (e.g. if a, b are columns only inside a multi-index, and c a normal non-indexed column, I can query: df.query(b==6 and c==4).  But for now, I'll use engine='python' with the query and lose the speed.

Comment: @techvslife I have a post on slicing multiIndexes that I think will be _super_ helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53927460/4909087 please consider upvoting if you find it useful.

Comment: I upvoted, as it's a very good post, but I don't see any easy equivalent to the query using loc.  How would you do this?

Comment: @techvslife If you are filtering on index level "b", you can do something like `df.index.get_level_values('b') == 6` to get a mask, and then proceed as usual.

Comment: I need to filter on a mix of one column of the multi-index with a regular column.  Even simple cases get unwieldy (where b column is index level 1:  df[df["c"]==5].loc[df.index.get_level_values(1) == 35].  Imagine when one column is being compared to another (e.g. a query for where c > b).    versus df.query("c > b")  or df.query("c==5 and b==35")

Comment: You could do `df.loc[(df["c"]==5) & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 35)]` but I agree that `query` is definitely a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks, that is simpler and works, but I think we also agree it gets quite ugly as the tests increase in number...