# Pandas DataFrames: Create new rows with calculations across existing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create new rows from an existing DataFrame by grouping by certain fields (in the example "Country" and "Industry") and applying some math to another field (in the example "Field" and "Value")?

**Source DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','Canada','Canada'],
                   'Industry': ['Finance', 'Finance', 'Retail', 
                                'Retail', 'Energy', 'Energy', 
                                'Retail', 'Retail'],
                   'Field': ['Import', 'Export','Import', 
                             'Export','Import', 'Export',
                             'Import', 'Export'],
                   'Value': [100, 50, 80, 10, 20, 5, 30, 10]})

    Country Industry    Field   Value
0   USA     Finance     Import  100
1   USA     Finance     Export  50
2   USA     Retail      Import  80
3   USA     Retail      Export  10
4   USA     Energy      Import  20
5   USA     Energy      Export  5
6   Canada  Retail      Import  30
7   Canada  Retail      Export  10
```

**Target DataFrame**

Net = Import - Export

```
    Country Industry    Field   Value
0   USA     Finance     Net     50
1   USA     Retail      Net     70
2   USA     Energy      Net     15
3   Canada  Retail      Net     20
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are quite possibly many ways. Here's one using `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
(df.groupby(['Country', 'Industry', 'Field'], sort=False)['Value']
   .sum()
   .unstack('Field')
   .eval('Import - Export')
   .reset_index(name='Value'))

  Country Industry  Value
0     USA  Finance     50
1     USA   Retail     70
2     USA   Energy     15
3  Canada   Retail     20
```

Comment: By far the best answer. The `unstack` followed by `eval` is a really nice trick — better than a second `groupby` and `get_group` I would have done

Comment: @BallpointBen `eval` and `query` are personal favourites of mine from the API. I've made attempts to popularise their use, but their usage is not completely understood. I have a QnA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/4909087), if you are interested.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. Very small comment - there is a closing bracket missing in the last line.

Comment: @coldspeed Actually I think there’s a better way… see my answer. `unstack` is expensive because it reshapes. Using the structure of the first groupby is more efficient, although it takes two lines.

Comment: @BallpointBen very crisp solution, nice! Although, I still like mine because it is a (still readable) one liner.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
df=df.set_index(['Country','Industry'])

Newdf=(df.loc[df.Field=='Export','Value']-df.loc[df.Field=='Import','Value']).reset_index().assign(Field='Net')
Newdf
  Country Industry  Value Field
0     USA  Finance    -50   Net
1     USA   Retail    -70   Net
2     USA   Energy    -15   Net
3  Canada   Retail    -20   Net
```

---

`pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Country','Industry'],columns='Field',values='Value',aggfunc='sum').\
  diff(axis=1).\
     dropna(1).\
        rename(columns={'Import':'Value'}).\
          reset_index()
Out[112]: 
Field Country Industry  Value
0      Canada   Retail   20.0
1         USA   Energy   15.0
2         USA  Finance   50.0
3         USA   Retail   70.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way to add those rows to your original dataframe:

```
df.set_index(['Country','Industry','Field'])\
  .unstack()['Value']\
  .eval('Net = Import - Export')\
  .stack().rename('Value').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Country Industry   Field  Value
0   Canada   Retail  Export     10
1   Canada   Retail  Import     30
2   Canada   Retail     Net     20
3      USA   Energy  Export      5
4      USA   Energy  Import     20
5      USA   Energy     Net     15
6      USA  Finance  Export     50
7      USA  Finance  Import    100
8      USA  Finance     Net     50
9      USA   Retail  Export     10
10     USA   Retail  Import     80
11     USA   Retail     Net     70
```

Comment: Thanks - actually, I wanted to append it to the original df. So, nice trick to do this all in one command,

Comment: Coldspeed‘s answer was a slight better fit to my overall code. Took from your code how you appended the result to the original df. Very tight result, though. Pitty that i can not accept two answers. But thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Groupby.diff()` and after that recreate the `Field` column and finally use `DataFrame.dropna`:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Industry'])['Value'].diff().abs()
df['Field'] = 'Net'
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df)
  Country Industry Field  Value
0     USA  Finance   Net   50.0
1     USA   Retail   Net   70.0
2     USA   Energy   Net   15.0
3  Canada   Retail   Net   20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer takes advantage of the fact that pandas puts the group keys in the multiindex of the resulting dataframe. (If there were only one group key, you could use `loc`.)

```
>>> s = df.groupby(['Country', 'Industry', 'Field'])['Value'].sum()
>>> s.xs('Import', axis=0, level='Field') - s.xs('Export', axis=0, level='Field')
Country  Industry
Canada   Retail      20
USA      Energy      15
         Finance     50
         Retail      70
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```