# how to concatenate / use strings to execute commands in python / pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation

i would like to use strings of "commands" to automate some pandas df analysis.

something like:

```
str_a = 'df.col_1.isna()'   
str_b = ' & '    
str_c = 'df.col_2.isna()'    
str_tot = str_a + str_b + str_c
```

then use the string to sort out NaN rows in df:

```
df.loc[str_tot, :]
```

this last should be equal to:

```
df.loc[df.col_1.isna() & df.col_2.isna(), :]
```

but the python compiler reads the str_tot as a [list] and not as a string, returning error.

is there a way to circumvent this?

---

thx a lot

I am used to this in VBA a lot to build SQL strings... is it a wrong idea into python?

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for such an unorthodox design? Where are the strings coming from? Are they typed by the user, read from a file, or something else?

Comment: You could take a look at [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), but it could be the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Hi DYZ, it' is just to build a bit of automation into my data analysis...I build the string on one side and then i feed-up a small function... why you say it is unorthodox? what would be the "orthodox"? thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

Close, what you need is [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), but if need working with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) function add parameter `engine='python'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'col_1':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'col_2':[np.nan,3,5,7,1,np.nan],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A  col_1  C  col_2  E  F
0  a    NaN  7    NaN  5  a
1  b    5.0  8    3.0  3  a
2  c    4.0  9    5.0  6  a
3  d    5.0  4    7.0  9  b
4  e    5.0  2    1.0  2  b
5  f    4.0  3    NaN  4  b

str_a = 'col_1.isna()'

str_b = ' & '

str_c = 'col_2.isna()'

str_tot = str_a + str_b + str_c
print (str_tot)
col_1.isna() & col_2.isna()

print (df.query(str_tot, engine='python'))
   A  col_1  C  col_2  E  F
0  a    NaN  7    NaN  5  a
```

Another idea is use fact `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

```
str_a = '(col_1 != col_1)'

str_b = ' & '

str_c = '(col_2 != col_2)'

str_tot = str_a + str_b + str_c
print (str_tot)
(col_1 != col_1) & (col_2 != col_2)

print (df.query(str_tot))
   A  col_1  C  col_2  E  F
0  a    NaN  7    NaN  5  a
```

Comment: hi thx a lot. this is close to what i was looking for. wonder if there is a more general function. Mine was just an example: I was looking to build a much more complex string. Also: this works for querying the rows, what about the columns? i.e assume I want to loc a df on certain rows (now I know how to do it, thx ) to change the value into the cells of a defined column. is there a way to "query" selecting the columns ( ?  df[col_x].query(string)= '123' ? ) THX a lot -

Comment: @BusinessExploration - Not easy, what you need. Maybe you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval), but generally some univeersal solution maybe is possible, but really complicated.

Comment: jezrael... thx a lot, I think you pointed into the right direction. I give a small view of the link you provided and the concept is there... even if I am quite surprised to see such a mole of info. using strings to build queries it's normal practice in VBA ( [DoCmd.RunSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql) ) ... I need to study...

Comment: @BusinessExploration - ya, each language is a bit different. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way you may use python `eval`.

```
str_a = 'df.col_1.isna()'
e = eval(str_a)
print(e)
```

---

For the upper example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'col_1':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'col_2':[np.nan,3,5,7,1,np.nan],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A  col_1  C  col_2  E  F
0  a    NaN  7    NaN  5  a
1  b    5.0  8    3.0  3  a
2  c    4.0  9    5.0  6  a
3  d    5.0  4    7.0  9  b
4  e    5.0  2    1.0  2  b
5  f    4.0  3    NaN  4  b
```

Will return

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

Comment: Should I remove the post then @BusinessExploration?

Comment: no, pls, it adds context. eval and exec where stuff i bumped in while searching for a solution...