# Check if rows of one DataFrame are present in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

DF1

```
 A   B
'a' 'x' 
'b' 'y'
'c' 'z'
```

DF2

```
Col1 Col2
'j'  'm'
'a'  'x'
'k'  'n'
'b'  'y'
```

And want to look up if the rows of DF1 are contained in DF2, and add that column Bool_col to DF1, like this.

DF1

```
 A   B   Bool_col
'a' 'x'  True
'b' 'y'  True
'c' 'z'  False
```

I've tried by looking up the concatenation of A and B in the concatenation-list of Col1 and Col2, but my data is giving me unexpected trouble. Any help on how to do this without concatenating columns?

Comment: `merge` with `indicator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True, left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['Col1','Col2'])
df['Bool_col'] = np.where(df['_merge']=='both', True, False)
df.drop(['_merge','Col1','Col2'], 1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B     Bool_col
0  a  x      True
1  b  y      True
2  c  z     False
```

**Edit**

As per @cs95 suggested in comments, `np.where` is unnecessary here.
You can simply do

```
df1['Bool_col'] = df['_merge']=='both'
# df.drop(['_merge','Col1','Col2'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This isn't wrong, but it's more unwieldy than it needs to be.

Comment: @cs95 I am still figuring out what `.eval` does in your answer. Can you please elaborate that?

Comment: `eval` is handy for condensing multiple lines into a single. Typically to perform a conditional on a column, you'd need to store the result as a variable and access the resultant column in a subsequent statement. With eval, you can [do this dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/4909087) using string evaluation.

Comment: PS: The unwieldy part I was referring to was `df['Bool_col'] = np.where(df['_merge']=='both', True, False)` which could simply be `df['Bool_col'] = df['_merge']=='both'`. You could also assign the result to `df1` instead of creating `df` and dropping columns.

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for explanation and pointing out unnecessary part. Corrected.

Comment: Looks better now, but you should still/also consider assigning back to df1. In general, df2 could have more columns than just col1 and col2, so dropping may or may not be sufficient here.

Comment: I have a question which might be important: does df.merge(how='left', ...) guarantee that the order of the elements in df will remain the same?

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge` with the `indicator` argument, then check what rows show "both".

```
df1['Bool_col'] = (df1.merge(df2, 
                             how='left', 
                             left_on=['A', 'B'], 
                             right_on=['Col1', 'Col2'], 
                             indicator=True)
                      .eval('_merge == "both"'))

df1
     A    B  Bool_col
0  'a'  'x'      True
1  'b'  'y'      True
2  'c'  'z'     False
```