# Pandas column selection with many conditions becomes unwieldy

Tags: python, pandas

Quick Pandas question:

I cleaning up the values in individual columns of a dataframe by using an apply on a series:

```
# For all values in col 'Rate' over 1, divide by 100

df['rate'][df['rate']>1] = df['rate'][df['rate']>1].apply(lambda x: x/100)
```

This is fine when the selection criteria is simple, such as `df['rate']>1`. This however gets very long when you start adding multiple selection criteria:

```
df['rate'][(df['rate']>1) & (~df['rate'].isnull()) & (df['rate_type']=='fixed) & (df['something']<= 'nothing')] = df['rate'][(df['rate']>1) & (df['rate_type']=='fixed) & (df['something']<= 'nothing')].apply(lambda x: x/100)
```

What's the most concise way to:
1. Split a column off (as a Series) from a DataFrame
2. Apply a function to the items of the Series
3. Update the DataFrame with the modified series

I've tried using `df.update()`, but that didn't seem to work. I've also tried using the Series as a selector, e.g. `isin(Series)`, but I wasn't able to get that to work either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with `update`

```
con=(df['rate']>1) & (df['rate_type']=='fixed') & (df['something']<= 'nothing')
df.update(df.loc[con,['rate']].apply(lambda x: x/100))
```

Answer (score 2):

When there are multiple conditions, you can keep things simple using `eval`:

```
mask = df.eval("rate > 1 & rate_type == 'fixed' & something <= 'nothing'")
df.loc[mask, 'rate'] = df['rate'].apply(function)
```

Read more about evaluating expressions dynamically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval). Of course, this particular function can be vectorized as

```
df.loc[mask, 'rate'] /= 100
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me ask, how might we accomplish this when several of the conditions use Series methods, such as .isnull()?

Comment: @ZAR `df.eval('col.isnull() & col2 > 1 & ...', engine='python')` works for me.