# Call the `dt.` type from a Python Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have timestamps in pandas and I want to be able to write a function that allows me to pull back different parts of the date. Here is an MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'hit': pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-29 00:00:00', '2019-03-25 00:00:00'])})
```

And this is what I want to be able to do:

```
def test(timepart):
    df['hit'].dt.timepart
```

So I could call `test(month)` and the function would return `12, 03`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strftime`:

```
def test(timepart):
    return df['hit'].dt.strftime('%'+timepart[0])
print(test('month'))
```

Output:

```
0    12
1    03
Name: hit, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks. i implemented the first `eval` version into my real script by the time you edited your answer, and it is working as expected. Besides cleaner syntax, is there a reason you prefer `strftime` over `eval`?

Comment: @bshelt141 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: @bshelt141 Please, please, please do not use `eval`...`.strftime` is OK if you want strings, but whatever it is, not `eval` please. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `getattr` to return that particular attribute:

```
def test(df, timepart):
    return getattr(df['hit'].dt, timepart)
```

```
test(df, 'month')
0    12
1     3
Name: hit, dtype: int64
```

The issue with `strftime` is that it converts the result to a string before returning it.

---

If you want a taste of the [dynamic life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval), try `DataFrame.eval` instead.

```
def test(df, timepart):
    return df.eval(f"hit.dt.{timepart}", engine='python')

test(df, 'month')

0    12
1     3
Name: hit, dtype: int64
```

python's `eval` is dangerous, thankfully there are safer alternatives to do the same thing.