# Shorter way of boolean indexing in pandas (Series and DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if there is a shorter way for boolean indexing in pandas? Nowadays I make like that:

```py
s = pd.Series(...)
s[s>0]
```

But it becomes cumbersome when the variable has a long name or if I do not have the Series/DataFrame stored in a variable.

```py
results_of_the_query[results_of_the_query['code'] == 200]
```

or

```py
stocks.get('AAPL').intraday_quotes.loc[stocks.get('AAPL').intraday_quotes['time']='9:00']
```

Comment: You have to access it somehow. Maybe look into making a view?

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval): `results_of_the_query.query('code == 200')`

Comment: Thanks @cs95, that is what I was lloking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `loc`

For `Series`

```
s.loc[lambda x : x >0]
```

For `DataFrame`

```
df.loc[lambda x : x['code']>0]
```