# How to implement arbitrary condition in pandas style function?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to style few cells in pandas dataframe and I would like to define a function that takes arbitrary condition and evaluates it.

## Note

There is a similar link [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval) which talks about pandas eval and query.

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df1 = df.head()

def mystyle(df, cond,x=None,v=None):
    return df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: salmon"
                            if eval(cond) # eval(cond) exec(cond)
                            else ""
                            for v in x], axis = 1)

cond = "x.name == 2 and v == 3"

# Note: the arbitrary condition only involves two variables x (pandas series) and v (value)
mystyle(df1,cond)
```

## Question

How to implement the function `mystyle(df,cond)` that gives output

[image]

## Error

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Why the `for v in x`? are you trying to format every column in the row?

Comment: No, only the value 3 in index row called 2 (third row of dataframe). Also, the cond is arbitrary it can be anything. eg. `v>3 and v<20`

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just pass the condition as a function or list of functions?

Comment: I have no preoccupied reasons, you can implement whatever method you like.

Comment: See [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval) for the various implementations of evaluating an expression with a dataframe.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I am aware with `pd.eval `and `df.query`, but here I am struggling to find a way to implement that idea here inside df.style function. If you post the complete, I would greatly appreciate your effort.

Comment: Can you provide some data as text and expected output for the expression shown?

Comment: @cs95 I need a function `mystyle(df1,cond)` that gives output like **EXPECTED OUTPUT**.