# How write a function for pandas style that reads dataframe name and values condition and colors some cells?

Tags: python, pandas

## Note

Similar link [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval)

This link talks about `df.eval` and `df.query` but does not directly solve this problem.

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df1 = df.head()

def mystyle(df, cond,x=None,v=None):
    return df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: salmon"
                            if eval(cond) # eval(cond) exec(cond)
                            else ""
                            for v in x], axis = 1)

cond = "x.name == 2 and v == 3"

# Note: the arbitrary condition only involves two variables x (pandas series) and v (value)
mystyle(df1,cond)
```

## Question

How to implement the function `mystyle(df,cond)` that gives output

[image]

## Error

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my 10 cents:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def f(x,cond='',c='lightgreen'):
    attr = f'background-color: {c}'
    df1 = x.astype(str).replace(x, '')
    df1 = df1.astype(str).replace('nan','')
    df1[eval(cond)] = attr

    return df1

cond = "x[x.index==2]==3"
df1.style.apply(f,axis=None,cond=cond)
```

## output

[image]