# Write a generic function to calculate a column based specific condition based another column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as shown below.

```
Date                t_factor     time_in_days
2020-02-01             5             1
2020-02-06             14            6
2020-02-09             23            9
2020-02-03             23            3       
2020-03-11             38            40         
2020-02-20             29            20               
2020-02-13             30            13           
2020-02-29             100           29           
2020-03-26             70            55
```

From that I would like to create a function that will calculate the column called t_function based on the values in time_in_days.

Conditions for t_function:

```
if T0 <= time_in_days <T1:
      t_function = (a1*time_in_days) + a0
else if T1 < time_in_days <= T2:
    t_function = 14
else:
    t_function = a2(time_in_days)**2 + (a1*time_in_days) + a0
```

Functions input will be data frame, time_in_days, T0, T1, T2, a0, a1, a2)

Expected output:

```
if T0 =1 , T1=4, T2= 35, a0=3, a1=2, a2=1


Date                t_factor     time_in_days     t_function
2020-02-01             5             1            5
2020-02-06             14            6            14
2020-02-09             23            9            14
2020-02-03             23            3            9 
2020-03-11             38            40           1683           
2020-02-20             29            20           14     
2020-02-13             30            13           14  
2020-02-29             100           29           14
2020-03-26             70            55           3138
```

I tried below code

```
def t_function_df( df, time_in_days, T0, T1, T2, a0, a1, a2):
     df = df.copy()
     df['t_function'] = np.select( (df['time_in_days'].ge(T0) & df['time_in_days'].le(T1),
                             df['time_in_days'].gt(T1) & df['time_in_days'].le(T2)),
                            (df['time_in_days']*a1+a0, 14),   
                            (a2*df['time_in_days']**2) + df['time_in_days']*a1 + a0)

     return df[['Date', 'time_in_days', 't_function']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.select` is the obvious solution here, but since you have pseudocode here why not just run it!

```
if T0 <= time_in_days < T1:
      t_function = (a1 * time_in_days) + a0
else if T1 < time_in_days <= T2:
    t_function = 14
else:
    t_function = (a2 * time_in_days) ** 2 + (a1 * time_in_days) + a0
```

Will now become,

```
T0 = 1; T1 = 4; T2 = 35; a0 = 3; a1 = 2; a2 = 1
condlist = ["@T0 <= time_in_days < @T1", "@T1 < time_in_days <= @T2"]
choicelist = ["(@a1 * time_in_days) + @a0", "14"]
default = "(@a2 * time_in_days) ** 2 + (@a1 * time_in_days) + @a0"
```

The "@" symbol is used to lookup the actual variables in memory.  You can now combine the power of numpy and pandas like this:

```
np.select(condlist=[df.eval(c) for c in condlist], 
          choicelist=[df.eval(q) for q in choicelist], 
          default=df.eval(default))  
# array([   5,   14,   14,    9, 1683,   14,   14,   14, 3138], dtype=int64)

df['t_function_actual'] = np.select(
              condlist=[df.eval(c) for c in condlist], 
              choicelist=[df.eval(q) for q in choicelist], 
              default=df.eval(default))  
df     
         Date  t_factor  time_in_days  t_function  t_function_actual
0  2020-02-01         5             1           5                  5
1  2020-02-06        14             6          14                 14
2  2020-02-09        23             9          14                 14
3  2020-02-03        23             3           9                  9
4  2020-03-11        38            40        1683               1683
5  2020-02-20        29            20          14                 14
6  2020-02-13        30            13          14                 14
7  2020-02-29       100            29          14                 14
8  2020-03-26        70            55        3138               3138
```

Read more about `eval` in my post here: [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: With a setup like this, you can define a "blueprint" for specifying algorithms which you can then parse from text files into condlist/choicelists that can then dynamically be run using `df.eval`. Not sure you can get any more generalized than this. Note that you'd only be able to define simple algorithms (essentially conditional assignment).

Answer (score 2):

Use custom function `fx` with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def fx(days, T0, T1, T2, a0, a1, a2):
    return np.select([days.ge(T0) & days.lt(T1), days.gt(T1) & days.le(T2)],
                     [a1*days + a0, 14], a2*(days)**2 + (a1*days) + a0)

df['t_function'] = fx(df['time_in_days'], T0 =1, T1=4, T2= 35, a0=3, a1=2, a2=1)
```

Result:

```
         Date  t_factor  time_in_days  t_function
0  2020-02-01         5             1           5
1  2020-02-06        14             6          14
2  2020-02-09        23             9          14
3  2020-02-03        23             3           9
4  2020-03-11        38            40        1683
5  2020-02-20        29            20          14
6  2020-02-13        30            13          14
7  2020-02-29       100            29          14
8  2020-03-26        70            55        3138
```