# How to parse elements from a pandas eval string

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a "database" which loads in dataframe series, only when they are needed. The user has the option to input user defined functions to create new series within the database.

Before I can use `pandas.eval()` on the string, the dataframe needs to be created from the database. Python needs to extract the subjects from the equation below:

`MC= ( RR + RR)/4 + @hypot(FL,RL) + @ceil(@log(FR))`

The subjects in this equation is `RR`, `RL`, `FL` and `FR`

NOTE: I'm aware of the eval hatred

Comment: What is the meaning of `@` here?  I don't recognize that as Python syntax, can you point us to some documentation for it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck To use a local variable/function in pandas.eval, a `@` is required.

Comment: @JohnZwinck there isn't much doc for pandas.eval - but see `Accessing Variables in Local/Global Namespace` in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval

Comment: I guess you need to reuse or copy some of the expression parsing code from Pandas itself, since clearly this is not Python syntax (if it were you could just `import ast` and use that).