# Getting NotImplementedError by using pd.eval() method

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample data:**

```
#importing libraries
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

#sample data
data=['{"level":0,"side":"Ask","price":"13745.75000","volume":"2"}',
     '{"level":1,"side":"Ask","price":"13745.50000","volume":"5"}',
     '{"level":2,"side":"Ask","price":"13745.25000","volume":"6"}',
     '{"level":3,"side":"Ask","price":"13745.00000","volume":"15"}',
     '{"level":4,"side":"Ask","price":"13744.75000","volume":"4"}']

ds=pd.Series(data)
```

So now I wanted to convert the string values back to it's original form(dictionary) so for this I used:

```
ds.apply(lambda x:eval(x))    #I know using eval is a bad practice
#OR
ds.apply(lambda x:literal_eval(x))
```

The above code(both methods) is giving me my expected output.

But If I use `pd.eval()` method:

```
ds.apply(pd.eval)
#OR
ds.apply(lambda x:pd.eval(x))
```

It is giving me **NotImplementedError**:

```
NotImplementedError: 'Dict' nodes are not implemented
```

**My question is:**

How can I use `pd.eval()` method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) is used mainly for arithmetic operations in pandas, so cannot be used for parsing `string`s repr of dictionaries like `ast.literal_eval`.

For more information check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamically-evaluate-expression-from-formula-in-pandas)