# Data access with Pandas eval() is orders of magnitude slower than regular pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, eval

Why does the pandas data access seem to work 1000 times slower when it's executed inside an `eval()`?

*Example*:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Without `eval():`

```
tic = time.perf_counter()

for i in range(100):
    df['a']
    
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Executed in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
#Executed in 0.0002 seconds
```

Using `pd.eval:`

```
tic = time.perf_counter()

for i in range(100):
    pd.eval("df['a']")
    
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Executed in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
#Executed in 0.9919 seconds
```

Using `loc` and `iloc` doesn't make a difference.

The performance is also largely the same when accessing more elements.

- `df['a'] + df['b']` - 0.0115 seconds vs 1.8803 seconds
- `df['a'] + df['b']+ df['c']` - 0.0259 seconds vs 3.0085 seconds

Using `eval()` directly on the dataframe, e.g. `df.eval('a = b + c')`, makes it only 3-4 times slower than the non-eval version (as opposed to 100-1000 times slower), but the original question remains.

Comment: Please use textual code rather than pictures that cannot be copied-pasted or edited. What about using `eval` and not `pd.eval`?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725355/when-to-use-dataframe-eval-versus-pandas-eval-or-python-eval